# Lottery ticket approach

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I have around 1 million records, witch are for answering questions during 24 days (one per day).

What I'm trying to accomplish is gather all correct answers throughout the days and make then a **lottery selection**, like, *if a subscriber answered all 24 answers correctly he/she has an higher probability of be selected than a subscriber that only answered correctly one answer*.

I'm using **Linq-to-Sql** as I fell more comfortable of using it, rather than pure T-SQL, even though this would be to be porter to T-SQL, but [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) helps me on that, so here's what I've got so far:

```
// all correct answers id's
var correct = from a in JK_ChallengeAnswers
              where a.correct
              select a.challenge_answer_id;

// all correct answers 
var query = from cr in JK_ChallengeResponses
            where correct.Contains(cr.challenge_answer_id)
            select cr;

query.Count().Dump(); // 978144

var random = new Random();
int pos = random.Next(query.Count()); // random select

query.Skip(pos).Take(1).Dump(); // get one...
```

This is straight forward ... and it's linear, there is no "ticket" approach, here a person that answered 1 question as the exact percentage of winning of the one that answered all 24...

**How would I go and try the lottery approach**, what should be my next step?

No need to show me code, I can get that, only the steps, cause I'm not getting them somehow.

Comment: Is it a straightforward weight, i.e. having 24 answers means having 24 chances? If it is, it seems like you have it correct.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Person, who has 24 answers will have 24 times better chance, than person with one answer

Comment: @SWeko exactly what I'm trying to do, 24 answers should have 24 chances!

Comment: @balexandre what you have in your tables Foo and Bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view with all the people's names that have answered correctly. Then you can use a random number generator to select the person whos id matches the random number. If you need more help ask me.

## EDIT

To me, the lottery approach is already working for you because each person can guess an answer every day for 24 days. That means they have 24 answers in your table with the foreign key that points to the correct answer. By doing this, I have a better chance of getting the right answer if I submitted 24 entries into the database. This would make my approach work.

Let me know if you had a different idea for how this would work.

Comment: Ok. That must be what he means by lottery approach. Ill edit this.

Comment: thinking about it, true, I already have such feature, as in `JK_ChallengeResponses` match one row per each answer, and with filtering that only correct answers would match, gives me exactly what I need! Thanks for opening on  :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a table of lottery tickets.
2. For each subscriber, put their entry in the table once for each question they got correct.
3. Choose a record from that table at random.